# Why default value of a field does not change in the compiled proto file?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a proto file as below:

```
message MyMessage
{
    optional uint32 field1 = 1 [default = 5];
}
```

And when I compile it with below command,

```
protoc -I=. --python_betterproto_out=. my_message.proto
```

I get below **init**.py file:

```
@dataclass(eq=False, repr=False)
class MyMessage(betterproto.Message):
    field1: int = betterproto.uint32_field(1)
```

Finally, I want to get the binary encoded representation of a message object as below, :

```
meessage = MyMessage()
message.field1 = 0
encoded = bytes(message)
```

It does not serialize field1. The reason is specified in the `__bytes__` function (the [link](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/python-betterproto/blob/master/src/betterproto/__init__.py)):

> 

```
            # Default (zero) values are not serialized. Two exceptions are
            # if this is the selected oneof item or if we know we have to
            # serialize an empty message (i.e. zero value was explicitly
            # set by the user).
```

I want to know, why the zero is still the default value, despite of setting it to 5 in `.proto' file? and how can I fix it?

I tried the `oneof` solution and it worked. But I don't want to use that.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with betterproto but its [`README`](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/python-betterproto/blob/master/README.md) says "It will not support legacy features or environments (e.g. Protobuf 2)." and [Default](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto2/#optional) values are only supported in proto2. I compiled your proto using the default (i.e. `--python_out`) Python plugin and the default value was correctly reflected.

Comment: @DazWilkin Which version of betterproto did you use? And could you explain that what dou you mean by reflecting default value? I mean how it reflected in the generated python file?

Comment: Yes, I'll add my repro of your issue as an answer so that you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my repro that demonstrates that `betterproto` does not appear to reflect the `[default = 5]` while `protobuf` does.

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip "betterproto[compiler]"
python3 -m pip protobuf
```

Ensure `protoc` is in the `PATH`:

```bash
PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/protoc-22.4-linux-x86_64/bin
```

Then:

```bash
NAME="foo.proto"
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_betterproto_out=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/${NAME}
```

Then:
`main.py`:

```py
import foo
import foo_pb2

# betterproto prints default Default (!) of 0
m = foo.MyMessage()
print(m.field1)

# protobuf prints annotated Default of 5
m = foo_pb2.MyMessage()
print(m.field1)
```

Prints:

```
0
5
```

And, `protobuf` generates `${NAME}_pb2.py` which includes a serialized copy of the `FileDescriptor` which uses [`FileDescriptorProto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto).

We can use `protoc` to decode this:

```bash
FILE="..." # AddSerializedFile byte string from ${NAME}_pb2.py

printf ${FILE} \
| protoc \
  --decode=google.protobuf.FileDescriptorProto \
  --proto_path=path/to/descriptor.proto
```

Which yields:

```
name: "{NAME}"
package: "{PACKAGE}"
message_type {
  name: "MyMessage"
  field {
    name: "field1"
    number: 1
    label: LABEL_OPTIONAL
    type: TYPE_UINT32
    default_value: "5"
  }
}
```